# Windows 10 Creator's Edition Fresh Install - Cannot change Personalization Settings

Tags: start-menu, windows-10-v1703

I just built a brand new computer and installed Windows 10 Professional Creator's edition. Everything works as expected, except I cannot change any settings under Settings -> Personalization.

For example if I go to Settings -> Personalization -> Start and move the "Show recently added apps" slider to off it actually goes to off. But if I close and open the settings or just go to a different settings page and back the slider is set to on again.

Also all changes made to the start menu are reset on reboot.

I already installed a second time with the same result. Both times Windows was properly activated. I'm using a local account, not an online account.

Thanks for any suggestions on what could fix this.

Comment: Is the machine joined to a domain by chance?

Comment: nope, it's just a home computer

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I am having the same issue, and mine *is* joined to a domain.

Answer (score 1):

If I create a second admin user account that account doesn't have the problem. So now I will just use that one and delete the first one. I guess some weird permission problem occurs during the set-up of the first one.